# Can I achieve Consistency and Partition tolerance over WAN with rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, distributed-computing, wan, rabbitmq-shovel, rabbitmq-federation

RabbitMQ gives two options for distributed systems - Federation and/or shovel which favour availability (AP) over consistency (CP) (and work over WAN); 
Clustering which favours consistency (CP) over availability (AP) (but doesnt work over WAN).

Is there any way to set up RabbitMQ and plugins to favour CP and allow mirroring over WAN?